# TikZ: scope fading doesn't work with \includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this example, the included PNG (the large rectangle in the middle) should fade from left an right due to the `scope fading` on a previous path. Why doesn't it?

Edit: I genuinely need a fade as I am trying to simulate a crossfade by layering a partially transparent image onto another image. Using `\pgfdeclaremask` doesn't really work as the source textures are being cropped to the left and right (and the exact dimensions involved may change), so the mask size can't easily be determined. How can I obtain a crossfade?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\tikzset{path image/.style 2 args={
path picture={
\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
\pgfimage[height=#2]{#1}
};}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[path image={texture_red.png}{90mm}] (3mm,3mm) rectangle (63mm-3mm,88mm-3mm);
    \draw[black,scope fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (63mm,88mm); 
    \draw[path image={texture_black.png}{90mm}] (3mm,3mm) rectangle (63mm-3mm,88mm-3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`texture_black.png`

[image: []]

`texture_red.png`

[image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/MidAg.png]]

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Why do you think that the included image should be affected?

Comment: @cfr: I guess a misunderstanding as to how tikz works. A better question might then be how to achieve the effect with the image fade.

Comment: OK. I think you may want to use `\pgfdeclareimage...` etc. instead of `\includegraphics...` so that you can use masking. This is around 1066 of the manual. Maybe there's another way but I thought that opacity etc. could only be applied normally to stuff tikz renders rather than including. (You can put something over the image but it doesn't affect the content of the included image.) So this maybe is a case where the pgf image inclusion is needed rather than ordinary graphics inclusion.

Comment: @cfr: Unfortunately switching to `pgfdeclareimage` doesn't seem to fix it. Shall I post a revised MWE?

Comment: FWIW, 87.4 says: >You can only mask images the are in a “pixel format.” These are .jpg and .png.< So it should be possible. But I don't understand the pgf internals...

Comment: You need a mask to get it to work with `pgfdeclareimage` and the mask must be greyscale (not just black and white). Did you try with a suitable mask? I would definitely amend the MWE to make clear what you want to do because cross-fading 2 images is more complex than fading one given that the tricks don't work in the former case!

Comment: I think you want something which cannot be done ;). But there are wizards around here so I'm likely wrong. I think you could (a) declare masks which you crop in parallel with the images (i.e. create masks the same size and then crop the same way in the code) or (b) edit the images outside TeX so that they are already faded appropriately and then crop them within TeX. Possibly (c) you could do some version of (a) or (b) within the TeX run using shell escape and external tools. What I think unlikely is that you can (d) do this just using the facilities of TeX and tikz. But I'm no mage... :(.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of of problems here.

In the MWE the `scope fading` in the second `\draw` command will have no effect on nodes in any subsequent path. To have an effect the `scope fading` should be applied to a `scope` or the node itself (as the examples in the manual show).

However, it seems that it is necessary to "flatten" the `texture_black.png` in order to get fadings to work with the image. This can easily be done using [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and will remove any existing alpha channel (which is what I presume is causing the problem).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [left,  scope fading=east, label=90:Original] 
  {\pgfimage[height=2in]{texture_black.png}};
\node [right, scope fading=east, label=90:Flattened] 
  {\pgfimage[height=2in]{texture_black_flattened.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, returning to the OP's problem, the `scope fading` needs to be applied to the node containing the image and the image needs to be flattened.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\tikzset{path image/.style args={#1#2#3}{
  path picture={
    \node [#3]at (path picture bounding box.center) {
     \pgfimage[height=#2]{#1}
   };
  }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [path image={texture_red.png}{90mm}{}] 
    (3mm,3mm) rectangle (63mm-3mm,88mm-3mm);
  \draw [black] (0,0) rectangle (63mm,88mm); 
  \draw [path image={texture_black_flattened.png}{90mm}{scope fading=east}] 
    (3mm,3mm) rectangle (63mm-3mm,88mm-3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To compile the above examples, the images from the original post are required, and the following image, saved as `texture_black_flattened.png`:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand your first point; the manual says "You add the scope fading option to a path in a scope – typically the first one – and then all subsequent drawings in the scope are faded."

Comment: @Mohan the manual also says "Scope fadings are also needed if you wish to fade a node", specifically the contents of a node (the fade will apply to the fill of the node, but not the contents or drawn path).